# Convergence in law of sample means of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

Let $\{X_n | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ be a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables with density function:

$$f_X(x) = e^{\theta - x}I_{(\theta, \infty)}(x)$$

with $\theta > 0$. We define the sequence of sample means by:
$$\tilde{X_n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nX_j$$

Prove convergence in law of $\{\tilde{X_n} | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ to a random variable with degenerate distribution at point $1 + \theta$ when $n$ tends to infinity. (Hint: $ln(1-x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-1}x^k$)

My try: I've easily proven convergence in probability (which implies convergence in law) by verifiyng that the hypotheses to Kintchine's weak law of large numbers are satisfied. From there the result follows immediately. However, the hint provided in the text suggests the exercise should be done perhaps by some other more elementary means, but I don't know how the expression of $ln(1-x)$ as a power series can be used to prove the convergence.

How was this exercise intended to be solved?

Comment: What is meant by "density" $e^{\theta-x} I_{(0,\infty)}(x)$?  Is $I_{(0,\infty)}(x)$ a function that is 1 when $0<x$, and 0 else? If so, the only way $f_X(x)$ is a valid density is if $\theta=0$, so $f_X(x) = e^{-x}$ for $x>0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, $I_{(0, \infty)}(x)$ was supposed to be $I_{(\theta, \infty)}(x)$ This function is $1$ when $\theta < x$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Okay.  So this is a shifted exponential.  So the mean is $\theta+1$ and the law of large numbers implies convergence with probability 1 to $\theta+1$.  What more is needed?  Why is a "hint" given with logs?

Comment: That is exactly my question. I suspect the exercise was supposed to be solved by some more elementary means, perhaps by using the definition of convergence in law.

Comment: What does "convergence in law" mean?  Is it the "mother in law" of convergence? =)

Comment: [Convergence in distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution)

Comment: Got it.  Now I see the point of your question.

Comment: I thought about it and I have no idea what the hint means.  But here are two alternatives: (i) Just derive the weak law from the Chebyshev inequality (this seems simpler than trying to use the hint).  (ii) Note that $X_i=\theta + Y_i$ where $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are iid exponentials, the sum of $n$ of which is $n$-Erlang.  Then the density of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$ can be written exactly.

Comment: @hallaplay835, missing a minus sign, $ln(1-x) = -\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-1}x^k$? And, obviously, valid for $\vert x \vert < 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment generating function of the random variable $\,\,\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}X_j\,\,$ is (for $\lambda<n$)
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}X_j}\right]{}={}\left(1-\lambda/n\right)^{-n}e^{\theta\lambda}.
$$

One way to justify that, as $n\to\infty$, this MGF tends to the MGF for the required degenerate distribution, ... that is, justifying

$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\lambda/n\right)^{-n}e^{\theta\lambda}{}={}e^{(1+\theta)\lambda},\ldots
$$

is to take logarithms of the MGF and apply the hint. That is, using the hint, one shows that
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\log\bigg(\left(1-\lambda/n\right)^{-n}e^{\theta\lambda}\bigg){}={}\theta\lambda+\lambda\,.
$$

Comment: +1: Nice post. This looks like what the hint was used for...guess you need to know MGFs, in which case, I'd think that Chebyshev should be fair game too?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have time for a full answer, but here's an approach that seems to use the hint:

$f_X(x;\theta)= e^{\theta - x}I_{(\theta, \infty)}(x)\implies F_X(x;\theta)=\left(1-e^{\theta-x}\right)I_{(\theta, \infty)}(x):=p_{\theta}\implies e^{\theta-x}I_{(\theta, \infty)}=1-p_{\theta}$

Now take log of both sides:

$$\theta-x=\ln(1-p_{\theta})\implies x=\theta-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{p_{\theta}^k}{k}$$

Which will converge for all $p<1$

Now, what you actually do with this to get the CDF of the sample mean, I don't know...perhaps Bonferroni or Boole inequality?